# Debug dll file with the dll source code C++

Tags: c++, c, debugging, visual-c++, dll

I Use QtCreator IDE with `MSVC2017` in MS-Windows with `QMake` build-system. For summarizing my problem with debugging, I'll give you an example:
I create a project named `library` with this files:
**library.h**

```
#ifndef A
#define A

#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
__declspec(dllexport) void some_function(void);

#endif
```

**library.c**

```
#include "library.h"
void some_function(void)
{
    printf("We are in the %s::%d\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
}
```

And i made a `.dll` and `.lib` from my `library` project. I used in another project and while i try to debugging i could see the `.dll` function source code:
**main.cpp**

```
#include "library.h"

int main (void)
{
    some_function(); /* Put the break point right here,
                      * And i could see the source code
                      * while debugging.
                      */
}
```

In the above example everything is right, What could be problematic to not let me see the my `.dll` source code while debugging ?

Comment: *"For summarizing my problem with debugging, I'll give you an example" ... "In the above example everything is right"* So then, what's the problem?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik *"What could be problematic to not let me see the my .dll source code while debugging ?"* , In the another project i could not see `dll` source code while debugging and i what to know what is the problem ?

Comment: You did not mention that in your question. Most likely, you don't have debug information (.pdb file) for that DLL.

Answer (score 0):

I just change the library file name extensions from `.c` to `.cpp` and open both the project at the same time in QtCreator.